# Express React Router Internal Server Error When Linked Directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I am using an express server to serve a create-react-app build.

server.js

```
// Express only serves static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  server.use(express.static('client/build')); // <--- this might be causing my problem, how to make work?
}

var api = require('./routes/api');
var email = require('./routes/email');

// Define API routes before the *
server.use('/api', api);
server.use('/email', email);


server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

app.js

```
class App extends Component {


render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route component={Container}>
          <Route path="/" component={Main} />
          <Route path="/catalog" component={Catalog} />
          <Route path="/product/:productId" component={ProductPage} />
          <Route path="/faq" component={Faq} />
          <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
          <Route path="/inquiry" component={Inquiry} />
          <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Edit: 
Updated my server.js file to show relevant code. I think the issue lies in using express.static('client/build'), but I'm not quite sure what to change it to in order to fix my routing issues.
/Edit

This works perfectly fine in Dev and Heroku where clicking links in the app go from route to route. For example being at the root, I can click on a link to "https://thesite.com/catalog" and the app navigates there as with any other route.

However, if I were to copy the URL above and paste it into a new tab/browser, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. This would mean the user cannot bookmark any page other than the root. Or if another site linked to a specific route on my page it would show a 500 error. Refreshing in a page that isn't "/" returns a 500 error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Because that route doesn't exist on the server, it's a client side router. So if you try and go directly to said link, it technically doesn't exist. You'd have to setup your server to redirect in order to do that I believe

Comment: Hmm, actually, I compared my app code to yours and mine is relatively the same. https://github.com/RUJodan/Source-React/blob/master/server.js poke around here and see if there might be a config difference? Here's the router as well https://github.com/RUJodan/Source-React/blob/master/src/index.jsx

Comment: I think you're on to something. I'm going to update my server.js file above to show what I left out. I suppose the issue is with using server.use(express.static('client/build')), but without this I am unable to load my production build on heroku. Is there another way to load the production build while also fixing this routing issue I'm experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add a universal route getter for express.static('client/build').

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  server.use(express.static('client/build')); 
  server.use('*', express.static('client/build')); // Added this     
}
```